# Working with Android Studio & Emulator, C:\ drive is about to die

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm new in android developing. I use Android Studio 1.2. It's making some large size folders in C:. ***C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator*** is about 5 GB. Can I delete or move the file. Or how can I change this path to another drive?

Comment: mine has 133 GB

Answer (score 1):

I am answering it based on Android Studio.(v1.5.1), Windows 10.

Most of those temporary files are copies of your app that is installed to your emulator. And some are because of the packages you add to your app using gradle.

Even when your emulator starts it creates a file of more than  1.3GB which disappear when you close the emulator.

About deleting the files. Yes you can delete those files and still able to do every thing you are doing, you can see all installed apps in your emulator and run them for test.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose these are system image downloading.
If you do not need emulator, these files are useless to you. You can remove them through SDK Manager.
If these files remain in Temp, just delete them

By the way,to move your temp folder : http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Location-of-the-Temp-Folder-in-Windows-7

Comment: This folder contains some .tmp files. I don't think these are system images of various android platforms because those are in sdk folder. I have worked with an app yesterday and these were also created yesterday. I'm badly in need of changing the path of this folder.

Comment: You can use mklink for changing the path ;
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278262-mklink-create-use-links-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

In Custom Installation option, you will have option to place Studio and AVD manger on other Locations whichever you prefer.